# Routing to virtual item

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-routing

I am trying to create a route in route table that routes to a virtual item (using a cms that creates url like example.com/about/company, where there is no physical file called company exists) using system.web.routing (unfortunately i cannot use iis rewriting/routing). I have tried the following but it results in 404. If I were to point to another physical file (tor testing purpose), the routing works fine.

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
    routes.MapPageRoute("about", "about/us", "~/about/company", false);
}
```

So, is it possible to point to an item like that?

Comment: Please have a look at this article which might help you with folder structure routing: **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77199/URL-Routing-with-ASP-NET-4-0**

Comment: Thanks but looks like in the article the author is also pointing to the physical file.

Comment: Yes, but if I am correct think you should redirect to a physical file and display the content depends on the value you passing. Also the references that article points have some good info !!

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting `RouteExistingFiles` too late?

Comment: @casperOne not sure i understand what you mean by setting too late? its right before registering the map. should it be somewhere else?

Comment: @xoail No, that's where I'd expect it.

Comment: @xoail is this an MVC application or a standard ASP.NET applicaiton ?

Comment: Its standard asp.net app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help you, this specific example is for Sitecore but the project is open source and I imagine it would not be too difficult to re-purpose the parts you need for your solution.

The gist of this is project is to allow you to use the MVC routing engine with a webforms solution. I will add the cavet that you will need to dig into the code a bit but hopefully will put you on the right track.

https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Mvc-Routing

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to accomplish your desired goal with MapPageRoute. MapPageRoute works by creating a new Route with a PageRouteHandler. The documentation for the [PageRouteHandler Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.pageroutehandler) specifically states:

> You pass an instance of PageRouteHandler to the Route constructor in
>   order to map a URL of a physical file. The PageRouteHandler object
>   specifies the virtual path of the physical file and determines whether
>   authorization rules for the physical URL is checked.

If this is an MVC application there are extensions for routing in the [RouteCollectionExtensions Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions). You should be able to use the `MapRoute` method and feed it the necessary default parameters to create new Route with an MvcRouteHandler like so:

```
routes.MapRoute("about", "about/us", new { controller = "about", action="company", id="" });
```

You'll need to put in the appropriate values since I don't know your controller design. Also, have a look at the [Creating Custom Routes (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs), which may be helpful for understanding how MVC handles routing.

If this is not an MVC app, you'll have to implement a custom route handler derived from the [UrlRoutingHandler Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutinghandler) and add a new Route to the RouteCollection.

Comment: This is not an mvc app. Any guide/example pointing at creating custom route handlers?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I think you may be able to just override the ProcessRequest method in your derived handler and have it do a `Response.Redirect` call. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680109(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In order to route to an extensionless target like `/content/something` you need to use Integrated Mode in the IIS application pool. If you cannot change this, then there's no easy way to do what you want, other than setting up a custom 404 handler, and manually dealing with the URL from there. This is probably the cause of your 404 errors.

Also, `RouteExistingFiles` should probably be false. You are trying to route things that don't exist as files. If you set `RouteExistingFiles = true` then the default handling for files that exist will NOT be used when a route matches. All you want to do is deal with paths that don't exist, but represent content from a database, right? So leave this false.

Finally, your `MapPageRoute` statement appears to be incorrect. For example, in Microsoft's walkthrough, it might look like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

```
routes.MapPageRoute("SalesRoute",
    "SalesReport/{locale}/{year}",
    "~/sales.aspx");
```

That would cause matching routes to invoke `sales.aspx` in response. In your example, the target is `~/about/company` which looks like a route, not an actual target - your actual target that handles the CMS request should have an `aspx` extension.